# How to add controls inside android grid

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

How can I add controls inside android grid layout so that it appears in each row according to data binding.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/favorites_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2">
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="14dip" />
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="14dip" />

    <Button
        android:text="Cell 2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:textSize="14dip" />
    <Button
        android:text="Cell 3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:textSize="14dip" />
</GridLayout>
```

I want this to be dynamic, without specifying row number.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say that Android Binding support such kind of things. The best way so far is to use [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) with custom adapter or [RecycleView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html).

Here is an example of GridView adapter:

```
// create a new Button for each cell
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   Button btn;
   if (convertView == null) {
       final Context context = parent.getContext();
       btn = new Button(context);
       btn.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
       );
       btn.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(context, "Button " + view.getTag() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });
     } else {
         btn = (Button) convertView;
     }

     btn.setText("Cell " + position]);
     btn.setTag(position);
     return btn;
}
```